# Problems between different locales

Tags: c++, winapi

The following code works very well.

The execution result is as I intended.

But I'm worried about changing the locale.

Is it possible to fix the locale to utf8 in the whole code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

static BOOL CALLBACK CallbackEnumWindows(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam) {
    int length = GetWindowTextLengthA(hWnd);
    if(length == 0) return TRUE;

    std::string title;
    title.reserve(length + 1);
    GetWindowTextA(hWnd, &title[0], length + 1);
    std::printf("%s\n", title.c_str());

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
  std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".utf8");
  std::printf("%s \n", "한글 1");

  std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".949");
  EnumWindows(CallbackEnumWindows, NULL);

  std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".utf8");
  std::printf("%s \n", "한글 2");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you call `GetWindowTextW` instead, and not have to worry about the calling thread's locale?

Comment: While you can reliably mix  Standard C++ code and Windows API use, the locale bit gets a bit more complicated. For instance, `std::locale` has nothing to do with the `..A` functions in WIndows. And those do not take UTF-8, period. IIRC they all map to the underlying `...W` functions with a hard-coded assumption that the multi-byte encoding is really just a 1-or-2 byte encoding, while UTF-8 often requires 3 bytes

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you. I made a very stupid mistake. I forgot to remove the "UNICODE" option while testing. So I've been using W and A in reverse for a very long time. I found it by your comment. Thank you very much!!